# Error " '(' expected" on line 5

Tags: java

Here is my program code. I am getting an error which says

> '(' expected, on line 5 [below public void work, on d braces].

I don't understand what is to be corrected there.

```
import java.util.*;
class Matrix
{
    public void work
    {
        Scanner Scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, i, j;
        char a, b, c;
        System.out.println("ENTER SIZE: ");
        n=Scan.nextInt();
        int M[][]= new int[n][n];
        System.out.println("FIRST CHARACTER ");
        a= Scan.nextChar();
        System.out.println("SECOND CHARACTER ");
        b= Scan.nextChar();
        System.out.println("THIRD CHARACTER ");
        c= Scan.nextChar();
        if(n<=10)
        {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                if((i==j)||(i+j==n-1))
                {
                    System.out.print(c);
                }
                else if(((i>j)&&((j==0)||(j==1))) || ((i<j)&&((j==n-2)||(j==n-1))))
                {
                    System.out.print(b);
                }
                else if(((i<j)&&((i==0)||(i==1))) || ((i>j)&&((i==n-2)||(i==n-1))))
                {
                    System.out.print(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    System.out.println("SIZE OUT OF RANGE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 5?

Answer (score 2):

You are developing java and this  syntaxt incorrect

```
public void work
{
```

basically this is not compiling because you need to add the parenthesis even if you don pass any parameter to that method...

Do this instead

```
public void work(){
```

and everything will be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Add method brackets: public void work()

Answer (score 0):

your are missing ..() this

```
public void work()
{
// Function Defination
}
```